# Remove _postgres user safely and completely from Mac /etc/passwd

Tags: mac, user-accounts, postgresql

I'm am attempting to reinstall PostgreSQL as I am unable to log into it at all.  I realise I had installed it a long time ago using both the installer from the postgres website and `brew install postgres`.  I have uninstalled both of these now:

- uninstalled using `brew uninstall --force postgresql` to remove all versions installed via brew.
- uninstalled [using `sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/uninstall-postgresql.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240197/539490)
- manually removed `/Library/PostgreSQL` (`rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL`)
- manually the PostgreSQL user (via the Mac `Users & Groups`).

However I have a `_postgres` user left in `/etc/passwd`:

```
$ grep post /etc/passwd
_postgres:*:216:216:PostgreSQL Server:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

There are no `userdel` or `usermod` commands available on Mac (10.11 El Capitan) and the [alternative seems excessively complex](https://superuser.com/a/180200/148811) (but perhaps necessarily so?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `brew remove postgresql`. Or investigate the uninstall scripts manually.

Edit:
Have you tried this?

- Quit Postgres.app & drag it to the Trash
- Delete the data directory (default location: ~/Library/Application Support/Postgres)
- Delete preferences for Postgres.app by executing the following command:
  defaults delete com.postgresapp.Postgres2
- Remove the $PATH config for the command line tools (optional):
  sudo rm /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

Edit 2:
To delete a user from the command line, boot into single user mode. Hold Command-s at startup.
Check the filesystem: /sbin/fsck -fy
If no remaining errors, mount the filesystem: /sbin/mount -uw /
Start up directory services:
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
Note that single user mode said to use com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist, but that didn't work -- this did.
Find what groups the user belongs to: dscl . -list /groups GroupMembership | grep username -- repeat for each group except for the user's own group.
Remove the group corresponding to the username: dscl . delete /groups/username (this may not be necessary -- you may get an error that the group doesn't exist; you can ignore it and go on).
Remove the user account: dscl . delete /users/username
At this point, you may wish to remove or archive the user folder in /Users.
You may wish to remove the .AppleSetupDone file in /var/db to cause the Setup Assistant to run when next booted.
Type reboot to reboot the system or shutdown -h now to shut down the system.

Comment: thanks for the help.  I have edited answer to make it clear I have already run this command

Comment: Oh - well, perhaps then reading the install/uninstall scripts will not be helpful.

Comment: I once messed around in the guts of OSX, assuming a normal passwd/group configuration. Even then it was a filthy experience. Jobs certainly made FreeBSD weirder.

Comment: Wow... that is intimidating.  Thank you very much for your answer.  Playing whack-a-mole with postgres has at some point resulted in success.  When I reinstall with brew and ran `createdb \`whoami\`` I can now login to a psql shell successfully :)  Thank you very much for the detailed answer.  I'm going to mark this as correct though I haven't summoned the courage to try it!

Comment: It is prudent to perform a backup. I am not sure why they got rid of the classical passwd/group system, but it is certainly possible regardless of this obfuscation. When I went cavediving in OSX, I was also removing a user account that wouldn't be removed with conventional weapons, but that was long ago.

Comment: IIRC, on a multivolume setup, if you have your Users folder on another disk, you must invoke `mount -uwa`